# UPDATE image in relation to mysql ID

Tags: python, mysql

I am trying to read the images from  ftp location and insert the data from the images to mysql and at the sametime copying the images another location. 
But my problem is it reads the image inserts the data into mysql table and  it cannot copy  the image into different location.

```
[![enter image description here][1]][1]
[![enter image description here][2]][2]
[![enter image description here][3]][3]





 def downloadfile(ftpobj, filename, camId):
        ftpobj.voidcmd("TYPE I")
        datasock, estsize = ftpobj.ntransfercmd("RETR %s" % filename)
        transbytes = 0
        myFilename = "/tmp/%s" % filename
        fd = open(myFilename, 'wb')
        #fd = StringIO()
        while 1:
            buf = datasock.recv(2048)
            if not len(buf):
                break
            fd.write(buf)
            transbytes += len(buf)
        fd.close()
        # Set the file to rw everybody for import
        os.chmod(myFilename, 438)
        print "Adding %s\n" % filename
        tmp = split('_', filename)

        tmp2 = split('-', tmp[0])
        vrm = tmp2[0]
        nationality = tmp2[1]

        cameraName = tmp[1]
        myDate = tmp[2]
        (myYear, myMonth, myDay) = split('-', tmp[2])

        tmp2 = split('\.', tmp[3])
        (myHour, myMin, mySec, milliSecs) = split('-', tmp2[0])
        myTime = "%s:%s:%s" % (myHour, myMin, mySec)

        dateTime = "%s %s" % (myDate, myTime)
        datetimeObj = datetime.datetime(int(myYear), int(myMonth), int(myDay), int(myHour), int(myMin), int(mySec))
        #imageData = fd.getvalue()
        tableName = "customer_1.%s_anr_vega" % cameraName
        sql = """INSERT INTO %s (camera_id, name, plate, datetime, millisecs, nationality, image_name) values (%s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s); """ % (tableName,
            dbutil.quote(camId, "int"),
            dbutil.quote(cameraName, "text"),
            dbutil.quote(vrm,"text"),
            dbutil.quote(dateTime,"text"),
            dbutil.quote(milliSecs,"int"),
            dbutil.quote(nationality,"text"),
            dbutil.quote(filename, "text"))
        cursor.execute(sql)

        sql = """SELECT id FROM %s ORDER BY id DESC""" % tableName
        cursor.execute(sql)
        tmp = cursor.fetchone()
        myId = tmp[0]

        sql = """UPDATE %s SET IMAGE=LOAD_FILE('%s') WHERE image_name = "%s";""" % (tableName,
            myFilename,
            filename)
        cursor.execute(sql)
        # Remove the image file
        os.remove(myFilename)

        datasock.close()
        ftpobj.voidresp()
        sys.stdout.write("\n")


      [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/yVrSR.jpg
      [2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/GC7Q5.jpg
      [3]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/hwOpv.jpg
```

Comment: What exception is being raised? Can you add to your question the exception and full traceback, or any error messages?

Comment: no exceptions /errors images not copied.

Comment: Is this client code running on your mysql server, or is it running on another machine? (`LOAD_FILE()` requires that the file be on the server)

Comment: Check the other requirements: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/string-functions.html#function_load-file. Make sure that the file is not too large and that your user has permission.

Comment: I have checked everything but no luck..

Comment: It's important to realise that if you want to load the contents of a file on your client host to a remote database server you can't use `LOAD_FILE`. Instead see [`LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/load-data.html)